# Create column that shows pairing between rows based on same value for two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a bit stumped on how to do this. 
Say I have a dataframe in python such as this. How would I create code in python so that all the rows with the same value in column A, and also have the same value in column B would be matched in third column C. So for example, if two rows have the value 1 in column A and they have the same value in column B, they would be grouped together in column C. So, even if they have the same value in A, they have to have same value in B too to be in the same group.

```
input                          output

a   b                          a   b    c  
1   5                          1   5    group 1 
2   6                          2   6    group 2
1   5                          1   5    group 1  
2   6                          2   6    group 2    
1   6                          1   6    group 3
1   6                          1   6    group 3
```

I know I can do something like this using np.where, but this is a large dataset, so I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of doing it. Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

use sets:

```
a = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]
b = [5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6]

res = set()
for _a, _b in zip(a, b):
    res.add((_a, _b))

print(res)
```

yields

```
{(1, 5), (2, 6), (1, 6)}
```